# Getting default message of Javax.Validation.Constraints from within a subclass?

Tags: java, spring

I have an HTML form that is submitting data to a spring post method. I've enabled validation with the javax.validation library and the @Valid tag:

```
public String openForm(@ModelAttribute("task")@Valid Task task,
          BindingResult result, Model model) {
          if(result.hasErrors()) {
              System.out.println("Form does not validate.");
              List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();
              for(ObjectError error: errors) {
                  System.out.println(error.getDefaultMessage());
              }
           }
           return "home"; 
 }
```

`Task` is the main object being binded to the form, but `Task` contains a class called `User`. User has a `fullName`. There are two fields that I am trying to validate:

`systemType` is a String within the Task object:

```
   @Size(min=1, message="The System Type must contain a valid option")
    private String systemType;
```

`fullName` is a String within the User object:

```
@Size(min=1, message="A User must be selected.")
private String fullName;
```

The validation itself is working, but what I am trying to figure out how to do is get the default message working. When I iterate through the `BindingResult` `result` for errors and print out the `error.getDefaultMessage()` the `systemType` error message works as expected.

However, when there is a validation error with the `fullName` field, it prints:

```
Property 'user.fullName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

I believe this to be because it is an inner class of the main class `Task` which is what is actually being validated. I guess I could just write some logic to say that if this error comes along to just print the error message I actually want - but is there a way to go within error and get the default message I originally specified?

Comment: I haven't used this form of validation, but when the error message is in a properties file, the class doesn't matter, only the validator and the field name, e.g.: "Size.fullName=Name must be at least {1} characters". So I don't think a subclass would mess that up.

Comment: Try to put a NotNull or NotBlank there first, maybe the form sends a NULL and Size doesn't like that.

Comment: NotNull is giving the same error, I'll keep looking around to see if I am missing something.